# Is this the correct use of the Bernoulli distribution theorem?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I need to solve a probability problem and I get the wrong answer, but unfortunately I don't know why. Could please somebody have a look at it and potentially give me feedback?

The problem is stated as follows:

The percentage of students that has a tablet is $83\%$. In a car there are $5$ students. What is the probability that more than the half of the students in the car have a tablet?

The correct answer according to the manual is: $0.9625$

The method I tried:

I assume that having a tablet is 'success'.
I assume not having a tablet is 'failure'.

So $p = 0.83$ and $1-p = 0.17$.

I used the Bernoulli theorem to calculate the chance of successes $k$ (more than the half of $5$ is $3$), within a certain $n$ ($n=5$).

I calculated:
\begin{align*}
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} & = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} \cdot 0.83^k \cdot (1-0.83)^{5-3}\\
& = 10 \cdot 0.83^3 \cdot (1-0.83)^{2}\\ 
& = 0.165 
\end{align*}

My answer is wrong, but I cannot see why yet.

Thanks in advance,

Ter

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

More than half of the students have a tablet means *at least* three students have a tablet.  You calculated the probability that *exactly* three of them do.  To that, you must add the probabilities that exactly four students have a tablet or exactly five students have a tablet.

Comment: I didn't think of that, but I should have! Thanks for your help (and edditing my question) :)